# Does NOAA still plan to deploy all twelve Cosmic-2 GPS radio occultation satellites?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, mission-design, earth-observation, noaa, gps-radio-occultation

In the 2014 Space News interview of Jim Bridenstine (now NASA administrator, then member of the US house of representatives for Oklahoma) [Q&A With Rep. Jim Bridenstine (R-Okla.)](https://spacenews.com/qa-with-rep-james-bridenstine-r-okla/) appears:

> **Space News:** PlanetIQ has suggested NOAA cut the U.S.-Taiwan Cosmic-2 GPS radio occultation down to six satellites. Do you think NOAA should launch all 12 Cosmic-2 satellites as planned?
>
> **Bridenstine:** Nobody has come to me and lobbied me telling me they shouldn’t. I think if Cosmic-2 is necessary to get that done, I don’t have a problem with that. Even if they launch Cosmic-2, there is still a market for more GPS radio occultation data. We in Congress are going to make an effort to put forth a little bit of money for NOAA to purchase that data. It probably won’t be sufficient money to launch an entire new private GPS radio occultation constellation, but it would be enough money to suggest that there is a market here for private entrepreneurs who are interested in providing capital to launch, and prove that they can.

Did congress "...make an effort to put forth a little bit of money for NOAA to purchase that data."? Does NOAA still plan to deploy all twelve 12 Cosmic-2 GPS radio occultation satellites? If not, what is the current constellation plan, and sources of funding?

A little background: GPS radio occultation looks at the effects of water content on the propagation of GPS signals as the propagation path moves through different heights of the upper atmosphere. These effects are strongly affected by water content, and so this provides a measurement of water vapor versus height which currently can't be easily made in any other way at these altitudes. These measurements are important for weather prediction, especially for catastrophic weather including hurricanes & typhoons leading to loss of life and property.

**below:** from [here](https://www.cosmic.ucar.edu/ro.html)

[image: Cosmic-2 GPS radio occultation]